# Perl to Java Regex conversion

Tags: java, regex, perl

There are some perl regular expressions that I need to convert to Java regular expressions. I'm new to Java and don't know much about Java regexes.

Regex that I want to convert are very similar to this

```
Text =~ /(^FOO[0-9]{4})|(^BAR[0-9]{3})/
```

See if string matches to either `FOO4823` `BAR943` (`FOO` and 4 numbers or `BAR` and 3 numbers). How would I rewrite this in Java? Are there any simple rules to convert them?

Comment: Start here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/? Come back when you will have problems with Java code.

Comment: What have you tried? Did you do any research on a modern website called google? and Oracle documentation? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: I don't know any PHP.  Does `=~` grab the part that was matched by the regex?  What happens if there's more than one match?

Comment: @markspace It's perl. It just matches with the pattern and returns true or false. That is all I need to know. If the pattern matches or not.

Comment: @sublime Ah, OK.  You have two answers below.  Pick one.

Comment: There are construct differences between Perl and Java, but with your regex the constructs are identical. Are you trying to do Java regex without having to learn the standard Regex function calls? This is not a good start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To re-write this in Java, you want something like

```
String text = ...
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(^FOO[0-9]{4})|(^BAR[0-9]{3})").matcher( text );
if( matcher.find() ) {  
  // ... it was found
}
```

As for a guide converting Perl to Java, there's a [pretty good discussion in this StackOverflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14030146/what-are-the-differences-between-perl-and-java-regex-capabilities)

Answer (score 1):

It would be pretty similar.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(^FOO[0-9]{4})|(^BAR[0-9]{3})");
System.out.println(pattern.matcher("FOO4823").find());
System.out.println(pattern.matcher("BAR943").find());
```

Take a look at the test [here](http://fiddle.re/8a0j26)