# Regular expression to validate if the string has "AND" operator at proper places

Tags: java, regex, string

I am new to Java.I am looking for a regular expression which will tell if the given string has "AND" placed at proper positions, that is, it is a valid AND operation.
Eg :

1. How AND why  : VALID
2. Try AND succeed AND pass : VALID
3. Try succeed AND : INVALID     ( since AND is at last index )
4. Try AND AND succeed AND pass : INVALID    ( since there are 2 consecutive ANDs )

Comment: Hi, could you please post your code as well?

Comment: Hi @mettleap : I was not able to write code for reg ex for this hence posted this question :)

Comment: This site is good for creating regexs https://regexr.com/

Comment: @AtahanAtay - regarding regexr.com: yes, but not necessarily for Java regexes. It supports "_JavaScript & PHP/PCRE RegEx_". See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14030146/what-are-the-differences-between-perl-and-java-regex-capabilities) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39636124/regular-expression-works-on-regex101-com-but-not-on-prod).

Answer (score -1):

Here is a small working example to solve this problem,

```
public class MyClass {
public static void main(String args[]) {
  
  String[] tests = {"How AND why", "Try AND succeed AND pass", "Try succeed AND", "Try AND AND succeed AND pass", "how ANDY why"};
  
  for(String s: tests){
      System.out.println(isValid(s));
  }
  
  
  
}

public static boolean isValid(String str){
    String[] splitString = str.split("\\bAND\\b", -1);
    if(splitString.length == 1){
        return false;
    }
    for(String s: splitString){
      if (s.equals(" ") || s.equals("")){
          return false;
      }
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

}

I am splitting a string using the regex `AND`. If AND comes in the start or end of a string, there will always be an empty string in the output of `str.split("AND", -1)`. Also, if an `AND` is followed by another, a space will also be there in `str.split("AND", -1)`. So I check these two conditions in `(s.equals(" ") || s.equals(""))`

EDIT:

In order to handle strings like `how ANDY why` you can use word boundaries `\b` in the regex, which will match the whole word. So a regex like `\\bAND\\b` will not match the `AND` part in `ANDY`. Updated the code above to reflect this.

Comment: Hi @mettleap : Thank you for the answer but it is failing in one of the conditions. If I give "how ANDY why" in that case also it is returning true instead of false. Forgot to mention this scenario above. Could you help me with a reg ex for this which will cover all these cases including the one I mentioned in this comment ?

Comment: @ishita07, you can use word boundaries. I updated the answer. Please take a look. :)