# Repeating subpatterns regex in C++

Tags: c++, regex

I have an input `...$1::integer,$2::varchar...` and am trying to count the amount of `$\d::\w+` patterns. So, I have this:

```
std::regex regex("(\\$\\d+\\:\\:\\w+(, ?){0,1})+?(\1)*?", std::regex_constants::icase);
std::match_results <const char *> matches;
std::regex_search(str.c_str(), matches, regex);
```

However, this gives the results:

```
$1::integer,$2::varchar
```

and

```
$2::varchar
```

How should I change the pattern to obtain `$1::integer` and `$2::varchar` as matches?

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
\$\d+::\w+(?=,|$)
```

Here is [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/iT4eX9/1) and tested at [regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%24%5cd%2b%3a%3a%5cw%2b(%3f%3d%2c%7c%24)&i=%241%3a%3ainteger%2c%242%3a%3avarchar)

[image]

Pattern explanation:

```
  \$                       '$'
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times)
  ::                       '::'
  \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or more times)
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
    ,                        ','
   |                        OR
    $                        the end of the string/line
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: I see the 'g' flag is specified in the demo - I assume that's the important 'search for repeats' modifier? How is this possible in C++?

Comment: Look at the tested site. [regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%24%5cd%2b%3a%3a%5cw%2b(%3f%3d%2c%7c%24)&i=%241%3a%3ainteger%2c%242%3a%3avarchar) and This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127463/convert-perl-regular-expression-to-equivalent-ecmascript-regular-expression) might help you.

Comment: Although it runs successfully on that site, no matches are found in C++

Comment: I don't know about C++ but it works for .NET. There should be something similar regex in C++. Let me search on google.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after a lot of experimentation and reading:

```
std::regex regex("\\$\\d+::\\w+");
auto els_begin = std::sregex_iterator(str.begin(), str.end(), regex);
auto els_end = std::sregex_iterator();
int matchCount = std::distance(els_begin, els_end);
for (std::sregex_iterator i = els_begin; i != els_end; ++i) 
{
    std::smatch match = *i;
    std::string match_str = match.str();
    // std::cout << match_str << '\n';
}
```